# How can i change size of interstitial ads in google play services?

Tags: java, android, admob, google-play-services

```
public void showInterstitial(View unusedview) {
// Show the interstitial if it's loaded.
if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
  interstitialAd.show();
} else {
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Interstitial ad was not ready to be shown.");
}
```

here  `interstitialAd`  don't have any method that let us to change the size of Interstitial Ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get to choose.

And interstitial should be considered a fill page ad. Admoib will serve up whatever it has. Sometimes this will be a full page image, sometimes a rectangular popup, sometimes a video ad.